get url of request sender to an endpoint in wp
Is there a PHP/WordPress equivalent to req.hostname from Node.js/Express to get the hostname of the sender of a request?
I'm working on a WordPress REST API endpoint with the following their setup
I need to retrieve the hostname of the client making the request within the handle_proxy_request function.
I've tried using the Referer header, but it's not secure enough for my needs. Is there a more reliable and secure method to get this information in PHP/WordPress? Any suggestions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

try this $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

this just gives you url of your website not url for client website

req.hostname just derives its value from the HTTP host header (see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname). This header is set by the sender of the request. But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host says the Host header should contain the host and port number of the server which the request is being sent to, not the host it came from. Although of course the client could in theory choose to put any value they like in that header, or they may not send it at all.

Normally a HTTP server will know the (public) IP address of the sender. You can do a DNS lookup to try and discover a hostname which matches that IP. But why do you want to know that?

because I have urls of some clients and I want to make sure if the request come from them Without using anything that might be circulating

well, since the client sets the host header, it doesn't prove anything at all. It's the same as Referer - they could write anything they want in there. And it's not supposed to contain the source host anyway, it's supposed to contain the destination

It sounds like you actually just need to authenticate your requests? i.e. the sender should provide some credentials, if you don't want just anyone to be able to use your service.

I will try using ip to validate , thanks

Remember though that an IP may not uniquely identify someone - public IP addresses are often shared between dozens or hundreds of client devices (especially for domestic or company devices behind NAT routers or gateways).

what are the most common ways to make auth without circulating

I don't know what you mean by "circulating" in this context?

Authentication is most commonly done using usernames and passwords, as I'm sure you know. In some cases, depending on the scenario, you might be able to to point-to-point authentication using certificates, or maybe you for automated systems you can use OAuth2 with a client credentials flow, for example. Anyway I don't know why you care if a method is "common", you just need a method which is secure and will meet your requirements.

I mean if I used keys they can be shared and so I can't let Specific people only to have access

That can be overcome by using 2-factor authentication, if you're trying to secure it to specific individual people. A key is no different than a password, in that respect.

let me explain what should happen 1- client send req to another page 2- I make sure he is in list of valid domains 3- I forward his req to another page which only accepts my page

I'd advise you to maybe consider integrating with one or more 3rd-party authentication providers (such as Microsoft, Google, Apple, Facebook etc) which users will commonly have accounts for anyway. This removes the risk of you implementing your own authentication system and getting it wrong, and also saves a lot of time, complexity and cost of setting up your own system. All of these providers support 2-factor authentication. They all have documentation showing how you can use their services in your own websites and APIs.

I will try to consider tis , thanks !

I make sure he is in list of valid domains...that doesn't make sense. Clients are people, their requests come from a web browser on their device, not from another domain

it does because in my case I want to allow online stores to have this access so their clients ,too

Yeah but you can't really tell if a person is a client of another online system, unless your system and their system both share the same authentication system, or you have some other kind of backend integration with that store which lets you exchange lists of users including unique identifiers for those users (e.g. an email address which they use to authenticate in both systems, perhaps). It's not clear what information you've currently got about these users.

So possibly you want some kind of federated authentication with the other stores authentication system, if they and you both have such a capability.
